# Unexpected end of file error afterv adding if else statement to my WordPress content template

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo

I've been looking at various examples of SO on how to solve this but no luck yet. Basically, I wanted to add an if else statement to my WordPress content template, which was fine previously, but now I get an Unexpected end of file message and I'm stumped as to where that might be. This is the original code:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php 
        the_content( sprintf(
        wp_kses(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'mytheme' ),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        get_the_title()
    ) );

    echo '<p class="btn-cc"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">Read More</a></p>';

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'mytheme' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );

    ?>
</div>
```

and this is what I did to it.

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
        the_excerpt('');
            } else {
        the_content( sprintf(
        wp_kses(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'mytheme' ),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        get_the_title()
    ) );

    echo '<p class="btn-cc"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">Read More</a></p>';

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'mytheme' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );

    ?>
</div>
```

So where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket } for else.

So the correct code would be:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
        the_excerpt('');
            } else {
        the_content( sprintf(
        wp_kses(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'mytheme' ),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        get_the_title()
    ) );

    echo '<p class="btn-cc"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">Read More</a></p>';

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'mytheme' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );
   }
    ?>
</div>
```

Which editor do you use? 
Try Visual Studio Code, it should give you a hint for missing closing tags or fix it automatically for you.

Comment: Well, first of thanks for that missing bracket but as for code editors, I'm on a Mac so I don't think VSC is available for that.

Comment: It is, I am on Mac as well, using it. https://code.visualstudio.com/ And also, this is not Microsoft Visual Studio IDE, its totally different code editor.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was a Microsoft product. Even the website looks like a Microsoft website. So you'd understand the confusion.

But yea, I downloaded and will try it. I've been using Brackets, but it doesn't provide that type of visual help.